# know which button call javascript function

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, express, ejs

I am making a admin page which show a list of post using  (I use ejs for template rendering engine)

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>Nama</th>
        <th>Watever</th>
    </tr>
    <% xprojects.forEach(function(data) { %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= data.name %></td>
            <td><%= data.desc %></td>
            <td><a href="javascript:void(0);"
                onclick="hello();">Edit</a></td>
            <td>Delete</td>
        </tr>
    <% }) %>
</table>
```

The **Edit** button(link) call a javascript function in another file

```
   function hello() {
         alert('This should show the "Name" of the table row which button clicked');
   }
```

How can I know which table row's button call the hello() function, and retrieve data(the 'Name' column for example) from the table row

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like Vinod I would attach an event listener instead of using inline-JS (`onclick`)

In your HTML every anchor-tag could have a number-attribute and a class `editlink`:

```
<a number="1" class="editlink">Edit</a>
```

In vanilla JS:

```
// Select all elements that have the class '.editlink'
let editlinks = document.querySelectorAll('.editlink');

// for-loop for each editlink
editlinks.forEach(function(editlink) {
    // add event-listener with click-event
    editlink.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

    // e.target is the clicked element
    let clickedElement = e.target;
    let clickedElementNumberAttribute = clickedElement.getAttribute('number');
    alert('You clicked number ' + clickedElementNumberAttribute);
 })
});
```

Or here:
https://jsfiddle.net/bblumenfelder/oaajf8Ld/

Comment: seems like the js loaded before ejs finished rendering the html so editlinks would be an empty array. I fixed the problem by wrapping it in window.onload... thanks you btw

Answer (score 0):

In the HTML add:

```
onclick="hello('"+ data.name + "');"
```

Then in the JS:

```
function hello(name) {
  alert('This should show the name of the table row which button clicked: ' + name);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you.

```
<script>
        $(function () {
            $('table').on('click', function (e) {
                var x = $(e.target);
                alert($(x.parents().find('tr').find('td,th')[0]).text());
            });
        });
    </script>
```

visit http://jsfiddle.net/gcq2019k/1/
Here